# Python returns JSON representation depending on encoded data

Tags: python, json, pandas, flask

I am returning json content-type from Flask using json.dumps instead of flask.jsonify as I am using some bespoke JSON encoding to handle Pandas dataframe datatypes

view.py

```
def post(self)
    ....
    header = {'Content-Type': "application/json"} 
    json_data = self.serialize_json(df, metadata)
    return make_response(json_data, 200, header)

def serialize_json(self, df, metadata)
    serialized = json.dumps({'classification': df.to_dict(orient='split'), 
    'metadata': metadata}, cls=JSONEncoder)
    return serialized
```

encoder.py

```
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, np.integer):
            return int(o)
        if isinstance(o, np.floating):
            return float(o)
        if isinstance(o, np.ndarray):
            return o.tolist()
```

The response headers seen by the client always contains:

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

However the issue I am having is that depending on the dataframe input into the serialize_json method sometimes the client response data contains a string representation of the data eg:

```
{ \"uid\" : \"1\", \"genus\": \"Felis\" }
```

instead of

```
{ "uid" : "1", "genus": "Felis" }
```

Trying to dubug in Python, logging the json_data output always looks like

```
{ "uid" : "1", "genus": "Felis" }
```

even for the instances when the client sees a string representation of the JSON.

It seems that sometimes I am double encoding the data, but I am at a loss to work out where this could be happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like some relevant part(s) of your code is missing, like the `return` in `serialize_json`. Most of the output is also missing.

Comment: what is the return type of `{ \"uid\" : \"1\", \"genus\": \"Felis\" }` ? is it a string ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus yes from javascript checking the json 'object' the type is: type:[object String]  but in cases where it works type:[object Object]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to NaN values that were sometimes present (input data varies) in the Pandas DataFrame I was encoding.

I fixed the issue with:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

prior to the serialize_json call.

Even though the encoded json looked perfectly fine on the server end, the client couldn't handle the NaN type as valid JSON.

Note prior to finding this I did try to hack a solution on the client end using:

```
try {
    testData = response.classification.data
    this.analyzedData = response.data
}
catch(err) {
    this.analyzedData = JSON.parse(response.data)
}
```

Which threw the error that it couldnt recognize a character (being the NaN type) - which is how I spotted the problem in the data.